# SET DATEFIRST inside function

Tags: sql-server

I have a database which holds multiple modules. The module I'm working on works with a different start date than the rest of the modules. In my module I need, at one point, to do some calculations that rely on the first day of week so inside a function that I created that does the calculations I tried putting `SET DATEFIRST` which, as I found out, doesn't work. To put out the fire, I've put `SET DATEFIRST` outside of the function call, but now I'm refactoring and I would like a better alternative. All the other discussions on the topic say either to set it outside the function or change the logic to not depend on it. The problem is that setting it outside of the function kind of defeats the purpose of the function and changing the logic is not necessarily simple as whatever I do, it needs to rely on a specific day being the first day of the week (it's not necessarily just one line that needs to rely on it). Additionally, the logic is already relatively complex (that's part of the reason why it's a function and not inline code in an SP) so rewriting it in such a way is both error-prone and difficult to read and change when needed so I'm looking for a better alternative.

So is there a better alternative to having a different `DATEFIRST` in a user-defined function than:

- calling `SET DATEFIRST` outside the function
- rewriting the logic to not rely on it?

I assume the answer is no, but I wanted to see if anybody has an idea.

Comment: Say, do you know about paragraphs?

Comment: @ATC is that some new fad? Probably not here to stay... Have you heard of improving the formatting of other people's questions by editing, though?

Comment: How about replacing your function with a stored procedure?

Comment: @TabAlleman I need to use the output of the function in another stored procedure which, afaik, is impossible (you can exec, but not retrieve data from a SP inside a SP, correct?)

Comment: You absolutely can receive information from another store proc in a stored proc.

Comment: @SeanLange as far as I know you can't get the data from the stored procedure, but that reminded me that you can put an `OUTPUT` parameter in an SP so, in my case at least, that's a good answer. If that's what you thought, please write it as an answer, otherwise write an answer on how to do it without output parameters. If there's no answer after a while I'll write the answer myself so anyone searching for the same thing can see the answer more easily.

Comment: You absolutely can receive data from a procedure. Using OUTPUT statement, output parameters. And you can even capture the results of a select statement into a temp table or table variable.

Comment: @SeanLange as I said, `OUTPUT` is a good answer, you can write that as an answer and I'll accept it. But capturing the results? I don't know how that would work since an SP can return multiple result sets. If there's a way, add it to your answer.

Comment: I always try to write `DATEFIRST`-independent SQL. (I.e. your second bullet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you replace your UDF with a Stored Procedure, you will not have the limitation of not being able to use `SET DATEFIRST`.

You can capture the output of a stored procedure inside another either with OUTPUT parameters as noted in the comments above, or using this structure:

```
INSERT INTO @SomeTableVariableOrTempTable (Col1, Col2, ... ColN)
EXEC MyStoredProcedure;
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. I was going to post this in about a half hour. :)

Comment: @SeanLange if you still want to post it (for the reputation) I'll wait for your answer to mark it as accepted since it was originally your idea. If not, I'll mark this as accepted. Thank you to both of you, though.

Comment: The rep doesn't mean much to me. Go ahead and mark this one.